# 'Unable to load print control' error while printing from reportviewer sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-server, internet-explorer

in our sharepoint 2007 portal we are using reoprtviewer to print. we dont have any SQL server reoprting server installed . and when we try to print either the IE closes or we get the error 'Unable to load print control'. 
any suggestions?

the IE verison is IE 11.

i tried changing that , its not working in any of the IE versions.
i uninstalled Reportviewer redistributable 2005 from both of our front end servers and installed them back . But still no success.

no logs .

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try:

**1. Server level**

1. First ensure that printing is working from Report Manager (open a report in Report Manager and print from there).
2. If it works go to Step 3, if you received the same error you need to install the following patches on the Report Server.

   - KB954606 - Security Update for SQL Server SP2

     http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4603C722-2468-4ADB-B945-2ED0458B8F47&displaylang=en#filelist
   - ReportViewer 2005 SP1

     http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=82833F27-081D-4B72-83EF-2836360A904D
3. Download and install the following update:

   - KB954607 - Security Update for SQL Server SP2

     http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5148B887-F323-4ADB-9721-61E1C0CFD213&displaylang=en

**2. Client level**

1. The Client Print Control is an Active X object. You need to be able to download and install the control. In Internet Explorer\Tools\Internet Options\Security\Custom Level you can find the settings to allow downloading of Active X controls. Please check if it is enabled for all users, try with an admin user as well. If it works with admin user, you may need to push the "Allow activex control" IE setting to all PCs in the domain.

In addition to this, you can refer this link for more possible causes and resolutions to this issue:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mariae/2010/04/13/error-unable-to-load-client-print-control-when-printing-reports-in-reporting-services-summary-of-possible-causes-and-solutions/